# How to calculate openX banner display portability

Tags: openx

Is there a formula or way to calculate the openx banner display portability

because i have some banner(campaign) are contact some are remnant and some of those has capping but some not

it seem the portability was quite hard to control

and i heard that openx will use old stat to calculate the priority of the banner too

so is there any formula to calculate it out?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. there is formula

```
(Banner weight * campaign weight / SUM(banner weight * campaign weight for all banners in the zone).
```

The easy way is to understand that first you got campaign, and then banner!

if campaign A weight is set to 50, campaign B to 10 and C to 40, this will be the delivery sheme.